# In Camel Rest how to handle request having slash in path param

Tags: java, rest, url, encoding, apache-camel

I am creating a URL like `/temp/{db}/{token}`

Here in token i have forward slashes i have searched and encoded it with URLEncoder and it is coverting the forward slash to %2F but still i am getting the bad request error because of slash.

I also tried the `/temp/{db}/{+token}` and `/temp/{db}/{token:.+}` but it not worked in camel.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can't do what you expected according to [URI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier#Generic_syntax)

**Solution:** Use a parameter named token instead

```
@RequestMapping("/temp/{db}")
    @ResponseBody
    Object temp(@PathVariable("db") String db, @RequestParam ("token") String token) {
        return  db+token;
    }
```

**Usage:**
url:`http://localhost:8080/temp/db?token=%2Fthis%20is%20my%20token`

**Output:** `db/this is my token`

Comment: i know this way but i am trying to create URL which has token in path param.